# replicate frontend command using restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I run a docker image taken from [here](https://github.com/NLPbox/stanford-corenlp-docker) using this command:

```
docker run -e ANNOTATORS=truecase,ner -p 9000:9000 -ti nlpbox/corenlp
```

When using the frontend the person/entity john smith is nicely identified:

[image]

The frontend issues this:

```
http://localhost:9000/?properties=%7B%22annotators%22%3A%20%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cner%22%2C%20%22date%22%3A%20%222021-07-23T11%3A18%3A21%22%7D&pipelineLanguage=en
```

decoded:

```
http://localhost:9000/?properties={"annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,ner", "date": "2021-07-23T11:18:21"}&pipelineLanguage=en
```

[image]

[image]

My C# code is:

```
var client = new RestClient(@"http://localhost:9000/")
{
    Timeout = 5000 // default 100 s
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};
request.AddParameter("properties", @"{""annotators"":""truecase,tokenize,ssplit,ner"", ""date"": ""2021-07-23T11:29:23""}", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("pipelineLanguage", "en", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

request.AddBody(@"hello john smith" );
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Unfortunately, it does not return/identify the person in the returned JSON:

snip

```
{
 "index": 3,
      "word": "john",
      "originalText": "john",
      "lemma": "john",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 7,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 11,
      "pos": "NNP",
      "ner": "O",
      "truecase": "INIT_UPPER",
      "truecaseText": "John",
      "before": " ",
      "after": " "
    },
    {
      "index": 4,
      "word": "smith",
      "originalText": "smith",
      "lemma": "smith",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 12,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 17,
      "pos": "NNP",
      "ner": "O",
      "truecase": "INIT_UPPER",
      "truecaseText": "Smith",
      "before": " ",
      "after": ""
    },
```

snip

If I capitalise John Smith, which I do not want to have to do, I get this correct answer:

```
{
          "index": 3,
          "word": "John",
          "originalText": "John",
          "lemma": "John",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 7,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 11,
          "pos": "NNP",
          "ner": "PERSON",
          "truecase": "INIT_UPPER",
          "truecaseText": "John",
          "before": " ",
          "after": " "
        },
        {
          "index": 4,
          "word": "Smith",
          "originalText": "Smith",
          "lemma": "Smith",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 12,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 17,
          "pos": "NNP",
          "ner": "PERSON",
          "truecase": "INIT_UPPER",
          "truecaseText": "Smith",
          "before": " ",
          "after": ""
        },
```

I could hack this and ensure that every word starts with a capital letter but in an ideal world I want to avoid this. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't truecaseText field what you are looking for? It's always capitalized there.

Comment: sorry I do not follow. did I make a typo?

Comment: In the JSON response, it has the name capitalized in the `truecaseText` field. However now I can see that it's a different `ner` type.

Comment: Can you use some tool like Fiddler to check the actual request headers and body your C# code is issuing? There may be something different in the headers that switch off/on case detection.